# Cannot find file in public/ directory (Meteor 1.2?)

Tags: meteor

I am writing a Meteor application template to illustrate various elementary features and am not able to serve a file from the public/ directory:

[image]

Yet this file exists in the [public/images directory](https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/meteor-application-template/tree/master/app/public/images).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try the following in your code: '<img src="./images/meteor-logo.png">'

Comment: I cloned your repository and I'm indeed experiencing the same issue. Really weird, I cannot find any issue in your code. I also tried downgrading Meteor to 1.1.0.3 but the same issue remains. I have a project running that version in which I use iron-router and public assets just work.....

Comment: I think your `public` directory should live in the project root and not in the `app` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was that the .meteor directory was not in the app/ directory, but in the directory above it.

This didn't cause any problems until trying to retrieve a static asset.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I really hate to say this, but all of a sudden, it just started to work. The fact that others have run my app and encountered the same issue makes this even stranger.

The repo's [README](https://github.com/ics-software-engineering/meteor-application-template/blob/master/README.md) now illustrates the appropriate behavior where the image is successfully displayed on the home page using:

`<img style="float:left" width="240px" class="img-circle" src="/images/meteor-logo.png" />`

I am at a loss to explain this.

Comment: And now, five minutes later, I run the sample application again and the image can't be retrieved. There is definitely something wrong.

Comment: I had created a test app which displayed the image at http://localhost:3000/images/meteor-logo.png, and the browser had cached that image which is why my app was working correctly temporarily.

So, it only "started to work" due to the browser cache. The original app still does not display the image for me.